# Using multiple WHERE clauses with this query not returning correct result set

Tags: sql-server, database

I have the following table, it contains information about clients and the products they have. I am looking to write a query that will return clients with specific products that I am looking for.

Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MainTable](
    [Client_Name] [nChar](10) NULL,
    [Client_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Product_Name] [nChar](10) NULL,
    [Client_State] [nChar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Examples of Insert Statements I've used

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MainTable VALUES ('Client_1', 1, 'Suite 09', 'VA')
INSERT INTO dbo.MainTable VALUES ('Client_2', 2, 'Suite 07', 'VA')
```

Table

```
Client_Name    Client_ID    Prod_Name    Client_State
------------------------------------------------------
Client_1       1            Suite 09      VA
Client_2       2            Suite 07      VA
Client_2       2            Suite 08      VA
Client_3       3            Suite 10      VA
Client_4       4            Suite 10      VA 
Client_4       4            Suite 11      VA 
Client_5       5            Suite 11      VA
```

So let's say I want all clients with the products, 'Suite 10' AND 'Suite 11'. Client_4 matches this criteria.

The query I tried returns an empty result set:

```
SELECT [CLIENT_NAME] 
FROM [PRODUCTDB].[dbo].[MainTable] 
WHERE Product_Name = 'Suite 09' AND Product_Name = 'Suite 10'
```

If I try an OR clause, I get results which I do not want. For example, substituting an OR for the AND clause in the above query gives me:

```
Client_1 * This client does not have Suite 10, only Suite 09
Client_3 * This client does not have Suite 09, only Suite 10
Client_4 * This client is correct, it has both Suite 09 and Suite 10.
```

What it seems like I'll need to do is write a query for one product, and then write another query for the other product using the results of the first query. Hopefully there's a more elegant solution!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I made some changes based on your suggestion, I hope it made it easier to understand what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks

Comment: Did those changes include the provision of CREATE and INSERT statements, and a desired result?

Comment: @Strawberry It does now :)

Comment: You're using SQL server

Comment: @Strawberry Yes Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 2):

Use `OR` instead of `AND` like:

```
WHERE Prod_Name = 'Suite09' OR Prod_Name = 'Suite08'
                            ^^
```

Which means either the `Prod_name` is `Suite09` or its `Suite08`

In your case with `AND`, you meant to say `Prod_Name` should be both at the same time which is not possible.

Comment: I thought about using OR, but logically that doesn't seem to make sense to me. Either it has 'Suite09' OR it has 'Suite08'. But I need to find the case where it has both. For example, using OR returns results that only include Suite08.

Comment: Sorry i dint followed what you are saying. Why would it just return Suite08 and not 09?

Comment: @SMA Using OR will return clients that have Suite 09, Suite 08, or both. I only want clients that have both Suite08 and Suite09.

Comment: @Strawberry yes i could use IN but i am not following what OP means by selecting row where we have both 08 and 09.